# Error message claiming my table name is actually a column in Java Derby (SQL)

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to create a new table with Derby (SQL?) and I keep getting an error claiming that the table name is not a column name in my table.

`Column 'CAR' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'CAR' is not a column in the target table.`

This happens whenever I try to run this code:

```
private static final String DERBY_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_DERBYURL = "jdbc:derby:cars;create=true";

public CreateInventoryDB(){
    try {
        createDB();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.printStackTrace());
    }

}

private void createDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName(DERBY_DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_DERBYURL);
    connection.createStatement().execute(
        "create table cars(itemid int, type varchar(10), make varchar(10), " + 
        "model varchar(15), caryear int, startinventory varchar(10), " +
        "datesold varchar(10), dealercost int, sellingprice int, doorwheels int)");
    connection.createStatement().execute("insert into cars values " +
        "(1, car, Ford, Crown_Victoria, 2010, 7/3/2012, 7/23/2012, 8900, 14000, 4),"+
        //etc.
}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the `insert into cars values`, as that is the only place where I am actually putting information into the table, but I can't find any other way to do this after searching around.

Comment: The error message does *not* claim the table name was/is a column name..

Comment: As a side note, you really don't want to use that format for dates... in fact, you don't want to be using strings to store dates at all.  You should be using an actual [`DATE` type](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefsqlj18730.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values need to be quoted accordingly...Derby is seeing `(1, car, Ford` as literals, so it sees `car` and sees, hey, that's a table...

Short answer would be to do something more like

```
insert into cars values " +
    "(1, 'car', 'Ford', 'Crown_Victoria', 2010, '7/3/2012', '7/23/2012', 8900, 14000, 4
```

For example...

A more accurate answer would be to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which will help prevent this and other injection errors, for example...

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into cars values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2, "car");
ps.setString(3, "Ford");
ps.setString(4, "Crown_Victoria");
ps.setInt(5, 2010);
ps.setString(6, "7/3/2012");
ps.setString(7, "7/23/2012");
ps.setInt(8, 8900);
ps.setInt(9, 4);
```

If you are trying to add multiple rows in a single statement, you could use the `addBatch`  functionality

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't escaping your varchar values, add single quotes around the values - like this,

```
1, 'car', 'Ford', 'Crown_Victoria', 2010, '7/3/2012', '7/23/2012', 8900, 14000, 4
```

Or, (preferred) use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [bind parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).